# How to make inputs a required field based on dropdown Select value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have the following dropdown select. If any user selects Op 1 from the dropdown I want to make all the following text type inputs a required field, otherwise it would stay as a normal field.

Would you please kindly show me how write this validation rules in jquery?

Thanks in Advance :)

```
<select name="something" id=something>
 <option value="1"> Op 1 </option>
<option value="2"> Op 2 </option>
</select>


<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" value=""/>



<script>
  $(function(){
    $('form.uniForm').uniform({
      prevent_submit : true
    ///*****What to write here??

    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `uniForm` plugin works, but if there is an option to make fields required it should get a boolean value logically.
so you can change your options value to `0` and `1` and do that as below :

```
$('form.uniForm').uniform({
  prevent_submit : true,

  required: $("#something").val()

});
```

Comment: Thanks Omid Amraei for your reply. I think you didn't get my question right.. So here I explain a bit My question was if someone selects the value "Op 1" from the dropdown select what jquery code to write to make the text inputs a required field. If the user selects "Op 2" then I don't want to make the text inputs a required field. Thanks :)

Comment: there is no known HTML attribute to make an input required. you can add a `required` class to your input. let me know if you want to know how you should add a class.

Comment: Its okay.. I have got an alternative solution. :) thanks for you time.:)